# GpuImage does not render properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

Currently I am working on an Android App with GpuImage Library. My goal is to apply filters on images via GpuImage.

```
GpuImage gpuImage = new GpuImage(this);
gpuImage.setBitmap(imageBitmap) // bitmap of the image that I want to apply effect on
gpuImageView = findViewById(R.id.gpuimageview); //it is ImageView
gpuImage.setFilter(new GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection());
gpuImageView.setBitmap(gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied());
```

This is how I basically apply effect on image via GpuImage and get filter applied bitmap.
But when I quickly apply effects to the image in sequence with different GpuImage filters
like shown below:

```
ArrayList filtersList = new ArrayList<GpuImageFilter>()
...
//Fill the array with various GpuImage filters
...
GpuImage gpuImage = new GpuImage(this);
gpuImage.setBitmap(imageBitmap) // bitmap of the image that I want to apply effect on
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
gpuImageView = findViewById(R.id.gpuimageview); //it is ImageView

//button that changes filter at every click
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(filtersList.size() > 0){
        gpuImage.setFilter(filtersList.get(filtersList.size()-1));
        filtersList.remove(filtersList.size()-1);
        gpuImageView.setBitmap(gpuImage.getBitmapWithFilterApplied());
    }

});
```

When I click on the button repeatedly and quickly,
I get a bitmap with just filled with a color like gray.
Is there any way to prevent this issue? Or how can I be sure that is GpuImage is done with the rendering before I apply another effect?